# Elasticsearch crash repeatedly after phrase prefix search on whitespace analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have defined my mapping as:

```
{ 
 mappings: { // defined all mappings },
 "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter" : ["lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

The query which I am executing is this one:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "*2AW\\-COTTON_\\&_SON_\\(*",
          "fields" : [ ],
          "type" : "phrase_prefix",
          "default_operator" : "or",
          "max_determinized_states" : 10000,
          "enable_position_increments" : true,
          "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
          "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
          "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
          "phrase_slop" : 0,
          "escape" : false,
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "id" : [
            "50010",
            "1604"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

I am using a whitespace analyzer instead of the standard one, as I had to search on special characters as well. I have escaped special characters in this search. But when I do a phrase prefix query on this index, my whole elasticsearch crashes every time. For the first two queries, it will take 20-30 seconds, after that for any further query, ES will crash. Right now, I was testing this on a 2GB RAM machine, with an allocated heap size of 1GB, can this be the reason, will increasing machine size help? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: How much data does your index have? Also can you show the query you're running?

Comment: Thanks, what about my first question?

Comment: @Val Have just around 900 docs only!

Comment: Do you need the leading wildcard?

Comment: @jzzfs Yes otherwise ES won't return docs for text like "EXTRA-HERE-2AW-COTTON_&_SON_(SOMETHING_EXTRA-HERE)";

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified a field to perform the wilcard on, ES will search almost all fields.

Have you tried using a `wildcard` or `regexp` filter instead of `query_string`?

If you *do* know which field you want to query (and I suspect you do), use something along the lines of:

```
GET fuzzy/_search?request_cache=false
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "identifier": ".*2aw-cotton_\\&_son_\\(.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even with 400 sample docs on my machine, the speed improvements are 40x over the wide-range `query_string`.

*P.S: Of course, remove `request_cache` when in production.*

Comment: there are multiple fields in which I want to search. will increasing machine size help?

Comment: specify them inside of `"fields" : [x, y, z]` or use a `bool-should` w/ the abovementioned regexes.